# AWK remove leading and trailing whitespaces from fields

Tags: awk

I need to remove leading and trailing whitespace characters from an input like this below using `awk`:

```
27 mA; 25 mA   ; 24 mA ; 22 mA;
```

Required output:

```
27 mA;25 mA;24 mA;22 mA;
```

What I've tried:

1. `awk -F";" '{$1=$1}1'`: doesn't remove the whitespaces, but removes `;`s
2. `awk -F";" '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,""); print;}'`: doesn't remove the whitespaces

How can I modify these commands above to remove all leading and trailing whitespace (0x20) characters?

### Update

Input *might* contain leading whitespace(s) at the first field:

```
  27 mA; 25 mA   ; 24 mA ; 22 mA;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*' -v OFS=";" '{sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"");$1=$1} 1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]*;[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS=";" '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"");$1=$1} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, making field separator for each line as spaces(0 or more occurrences) followed by `;` which is further followed by 0 or more occurrences of spaces. Setting `OFS` as `;`. In main program, re-assigning 1st field, then simply printing line.

***2nd solution:*** As per @jhnc nice suggestion in comments, you could try with your shown samples.

```
awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"");gsub(/ *; */,";")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/ *; */,";")}1` ?

Comment: @jhnc, sure, I added it in my answer as a 2nd solution, thanks for letting know.

Comment: Neither solutions will remove a whitespace from the first field's head, could you guys finetune those nice one-liners please?

Comment: @Daniel, Ok, could you please try `awk -F'[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*' -v OFS=";" '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"");$1=$1} 1 file` once and let me know if this helps you?

Answer (score 2):

A simple `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]*;[[:blank:]]*/;/g; s/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$//' file

27 mA;25 mA;24 mA;22 mA;
```

or this `awk`:

```sh
awk '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]*;[[:blank:]]*/, ";"); gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/, "")} 1' file
```

Comment: awk won't remove the leading whitespace from the very first field (if it has one)

Comment: Both sed and awk answers are updated. It takes care of leading as as well as trailing whitespaces.